# jquery form plugin doesnot working

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I write a code that submit a form to another page without loading like ajax.I use jquery form plugin.but the problem is it is not working.
here is my code

```
<div id='preview'></div>
<form  action='ajaxcall.php' id='upload_pic' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>

<input type='file' id='pic' name='picture'>
<input type='button' id='sub'>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jqueryform.js'></script>
<script>
var options=
{
 target:'#preview',
 url:'ajaxcall.php',
 success:function(){

document.getElementById("upload_pic").reset();
}
};

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
    $('#upload_pic').ajaxForm(options).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

I understand that the ajaxForm() function is not working.the jquery file is above the code and working fine.After clicking button page automatically redirected to ajaxcall.php page.please help me finding out the error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you included jQuery.js script before using jqueryform.js ..?

Comment: any error in the console

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you need to use ajaxSubmit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        target : '#preview',
        url : 'ajaxcall.php',
        success : function() {
            document.getElementById("upload_pic").reset();
        }
    };

    $("#sub").click(function() {
        $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
        $('#upload_pic').ajaxSubmit(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: no error in fire fox console but when the page load google crome console shows 'Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" '

Comment: is the click function getting called

Comment: yes,click is getting called because jquery.js work fine but the form plugin does not work as a result the ajaxForm() or ajaxSubmit() function does not work.but why the plugin does not working

Answer (score 0):

Add one more submit function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#upload_pic').submit(function(e){ // <---pass event here
      e.preventDefault();  //<----------------stop it here
  });
  $("#sub").click(function(){
     $('#preview').html("<img src='images/loader.gif' alt='Loading.....'/>");
     $('#upload_pic').ajaxForm(options).submit();
  });
});
```

Try to stop the submit before the click.